# Not able to publish updated version of app in Google Play Store

Tags: android, publishing

I already had a version (versioncode=2) in Google Store. Yesterday after doing some changes, when I tried publishing the app, i am getting below error message and not able to publish the updates. Any idea how can I fix it?

`This configuration cannot be published for the following reason(s):
Version 2 is not served to any device configuration: all devices that might receive version 2 would receive version 3.
Some devices are eligible to run multiple APKs. In such a scenario, the device will receive the APK with the higher version code.`

FYI, the new version is `versioncode=3`

Comment: One more point to add: Developer Console in Google Store shows status of versioncode=3 as "Draft in Prod" and for versioncode=2 as "in Prod".

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You need to "Deactivate" the current apk in order to actually publish the new apk.

Comment: I can't do this, I get `You must have at least one active APK.` error message.

Answer (score 6):

Deactivate the 2 version on the Google Play.

All this says is that version 3 is applicable for all devices that version 2 is applicable for. This means version 2 is obsolete.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. After deactivating, I have only 3 options for versioncode 3: "Move to Alpha", "Move to Beta", "Delete".. Should I delete and upload again?

Answer (score 0):

If you check closely, when you upload your APK there is no option to Publish to production, only Save as Draft. This happened to me last night and drove me crazy. Now, in the morning I uploaded the new APK again and the Publish to production button was there! I don't what caused this issue but now it's fine.

Comment: You were probably in Advanced Mode and not Simple Mode ... ?

Comment: I don't remember, but I pulled my hair out on it